# Stop sending contact form emails to consumer in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, email, contact-form

I want to Stop sending contact form emails to consumer in magento2.2.5?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I comment those lines, the email is being sent.

Comment: The email should not send to the consumer who is typing the contact detail form.

Comment: The email is being sent to the consumer..